# How to revert motion config to default state?

Tags: motion

I've changed way too many things in my `motion.conf` and I would like to revert it to its original state.

Is there any command to achieve that?

When I remove config file and during installation or even removal by `apt-get` I get following error:

`chmod: cannot access '/etc/motion/motion.conf': No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you installed it using `apt-get`, you can remove it and its config files with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get purge motion
```

and then reinstall with:

```
sudo apt-get install motion
```

You may want to investigate etckeeper, to avoid having to uninstall and reinstall in future. It uses version control to track changes to your /etc directory, allowing you to test and roll back config changes. You can read more about it on our [blog](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/146996830774/tracking-your-systems-configuration-changes-with).